# VSCode extension, trigger event when a word is clicked

Tags: vscode-extensions

On VSCode extension there is a method that triggers an event when clicking on a word? Similar thing with "registerHoverProvider" but for mouse click, not for mouse over?

Comment: That would be changing the selection, so look at `onDidChangeTextEditorSelection()`.